# can't connect airflow to google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am trying to setup a Google Cloud Platform connection with apache airflow using JSON key file,
I got this error when I trigger the DAG:

ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/AIRFLOW1/secret/key.json'

I tried '/AIRFLOW1/secret/key.json' also got the same issue.

Am using Windows 10 as OS and Ubuntu 20.04 as a subsystem where my airflow webserver is running.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys, I have solved the problem myself.
I share the solution :

instead of defining the keyPath in this way: "C:/AIRFLOW1/secret/key.json"

the right way is to define it like that: "/c/AIRFLOW1/secret/key.json"